# iPhone does not reconnect to WiFi automatically

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

I recently upgraded my iPhone from XR to 13. I still use it mostly at the same two locations (home and work). XR used to automatically connect to WiFi when I arrived to a location. If I was at home or work more than a few minutes, it would always be connected to WiFi. My MacBook is usually able to reconnect automatically as well. With 13, it frequently does not connect even if I don't move for more than an hour. If I turn WiFi off and on or toggle airplane mode, it will reconnect, so it clearly knows that it should be connecting. I tried resetting network settings, but that did not help. Is there something else that could be causing this?

Comment: Check the wifi automatic connection settings : one for general wifi, and the other in each wifi network setting.

Comment: If there was a problem with auto-connect, then I assume it would not connect after airplane mode.